# How do I extract the date from a substring in excel when date format varies?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, substring

I'm trying to extract dates from the substring in column D2/D3 in column L2/L3. However, the date format within a substring differs. Sometimes the dates are entered in MM/YY format, or MM/YYYY format. Right now I'm using the formula below, but I have to change the 5 to 7, when the date in the substring is entered in MM/YYYY format.

=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2)-2,5),"-",""),"/","/01/")*1

[example of substring in column D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO5Wu.png)

Comment: Ok, so is your question: I have a column (D) with cells containing strings than contain dates. The dates are all MM/YY or MM/YYYY. How do I extract the date part from the string in column D, and put it into corresponding row in L? If I have interpreted what you want, could you please reword your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Can you be sure that the only `/` in your cell will be the date separator and not just a loosely placed `/`?  Are you open to using VBA?  Maybe you could adapt one of the answers to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1272456/extracting-date-from-a-string-without-pattern

Comment: @Michelle Yes, I'm trying to extract the date part from column D, & put it into the corresponding row in column L. The dates are either in MM/YY or MM/YYYY format - my formula works only for MM/YY. How do I fix the formula so it'll extract the dates in whatever format they might be in, & put it into column L, without having to manually fix the formula when it's in MM/YYYY format?

Answer (score 1):

If there will *always* be exactly 1 slash, then you can use a two step formula.  Assume it is MM/YYYY.  Try to extract that first as a date.  If that fails, then it's the MM/YY format.

```
=IFERROR(
  DATE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)+1,4),SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)-2,2), "-", ""),1),
  DATE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)+1,2)+2000,SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)-2,2), "-", ""),1)
)      \-----------------------------/ \---------------------------------------------/ ^
                       |                                      |                        |
                     year                                   month                     day
```

I had to use a function `DATE()` to build a real date value, so that if it fails it will return an error, so that it will use the second part to use a two digit year.  (Don't include the `year/month/day` note in the actual formula...)

Or even better, since your formula already works for MM/YY, then if the first `DATE()` conversion fails, it will use your formula.  That way you don't have to assume a YY value is the year 2000 or later...

```
=IFERROR(
  DATE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)+1,4),SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2,1)-2,2), "-", ""),1),
  SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(D2,FIND("/",D2)-2,5),"-",""),"/","/01/")*1
)
```